# TabControl в стиле VisualStudio

Tags: c#, winforms

Как бы в C# WinForms сделать TabControl в стиле VisualStudio, чтобы табы можно было перемещать в виде новых окон и помещать обратно в главное окно?

Comment: это называется DockPanels, можно воспользоваться готовыми. например [реализация devexpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockPaneltopic)

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress ради этого покупать - перебор. Нашел бесплатную реализацию от WeifenLuo. Там, правда, немного подправить пришлось под меня, но все остальное устраивает.

Comment: это просто был пример уже готовой, собственно реализаций куча